# AWS Cloud Watch get metrics from DocumentDB in Node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-documentdb

I have a problem with my server task queue, its taking too much ram from the documentdb and causes it to crash.
I am trying to monitor the freeable ram memory from the documentdb metrics using the @aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch but haven't succeed.

---

```
  const clientWatch = new CloudWatchClient({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
    region: "eu-west-1",
  });
  await clientWatch
    .send(
      new GetMetricDataCommand({
        StartTime: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000),
        EndTime: new Date(),
        MetricDataQueries: [
          {
            Id: "?????????",
            MetricStat: {
              Metric: {
                Dimensions: [
                  {
                    Name: "??????????????",
                    Value: "???????????",
                  },
                ],
                MetricName: "??????????",
                Namespace: "????????",
              },
              Period: 300,
              Stat: "Average",
              Unit: "Count",
            },
            ReturnData: true,
          },
        ],
      })
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.MetricDataResults);
    });
```

Please tell me what exactly to fill in the MetricDataQueries to get what I need from documentdb instance....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **FreeableMemory** metric. Try changing your command like this:

```
 const result = await client.send(
      new GetMetricDataCommand({
      StartTime: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000),
      EndTime: new Date(),
      MetricDataQueries: [
          {
            // You can choose a unique name
            Id: "memory",
            MetricStat: {
              Metric: {
                Dimensions: [
                  {
                    Name: "DBClusterIdentifier",
                    Value: "{name of your Cluster identifier}",
                  },
                ],
                MetricName: "FreeableMemory",
                Namespace: "AWS/DocDB",
              },
              Period: 300,
              Stat: "Average",
              // You should change the unit as well
              Unit: "Bytes",
            },
            ReturnData: true,
          },
        ],
      })
    );
```

---

You can check the values for Namespace, Metric name, and Dimensions:

1. Click on **View in Metrics**
2. Click on the Details column of the metric

Comment: Thank you I've already managed to get it,
Any idea how to get it in real-time? (Not an avarage by the minute but the exact free memory when requested....)

Comment: @NoamAzoulay You can accept the answer. You can try CloudWatch Alarm to notify you when the memory is above a threshold.